# Can not get data from multiple SQLite table in Android application

Tags: android, sqlite, illegalstateexception

In my application, there is a few lines of code for retrieving data from multiple database.

Code:

```
String testquiry = "select a.rowid as _id, "
                    + "a.delivery_seq sequence, "
                    + "a.chinese_name chinese_name, "
                    + "b.cust_code cust_code, "             
                    + "a.status status "
                    + "from route_cust a, customer_file b, pda c "
                    + "where a.cust_code = b.cust_code "
                    + "and b.cust_status = 'A' "
                    + "and b.route = c.route "              
                    + "and c.default_route = 'Y' "
                    + "order by a.delivery_seq";


String testResult;

Cursor testCur = db.rawQuery(testquiry, null);
    if(testCur.moveToFirst()){
        testResult = testCur.getString(cur_getimportcsv.getColumnIndex("status"));
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), testResult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

testCur.close();
```

When the application run to the following code, errors occur.

```
testResult = testCur.getString(cur_getimportcsv.getColumnIndex("status"));
```

Error displayed in LogCat:

```
09-03 15:53:36.533: W/dalvikvm(23398): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415abba8)
09-03 15:53:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23398): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-03 15:53:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23398): Process: com.iceapp, PID: 23398
09-03 15:53:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23398): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
09-03 15:53:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):    at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
09-03 15:53:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
09-03 15:53:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
09-03 15:53:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):    at com.iceapp.ImportCsvActivity$2.onClick(ImportCsvActivity.java:285)
09-03 15:53:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
09-03 15:53:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
09-03 15:53:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-03 15:53:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-03 15:53:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-03 15:53:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
09-03 15:53:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-03 15:53:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-03 15:53:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
09-03 15:53:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
09-03 15:53:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(23398):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have studied other similar question on stackoverflow, I found that this problem was caused by unsuccessful fetch of column "status". Can anyone give me some help? Why the value of 'status' cannot be got successfully??

Comment: you should get column index from `testCur` not from `cur_getimportcsv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using different cursor (`cur_getimportcsv`) as the reference for finding column "status". It might be exist, or it might be not. In this case, it is not: there is no "status" on `cur_getimportcsv`, returning "-1" for the position.

It's almost never safe to use different cursor when manipulating a cursor. The solution is to use same cursor all the way.

```
testResult = testCur.getString(testCur.getColumnIndex("status"));
```

Comment: Thank you, I did't see this careless mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read only the first row, you can do

```
testCur.moveToFirst();
if (!testCur.isAfterLast()) {
    testResult = testCur.getString(testCur.getColumnIndex("status"));
}
```

#### Edit:

You can iterate through your cursor as follows

```
testCur.moveToFirst();
while (testCur.isAfterLast() == false) 
{
    testResult = testCur.getString(testCur.getColumnIndex("status"));

    // implement your logic here       

    cur.moveToNext();
}
```

Comment: @Selvin Yes, I want to read the first row only, but I will try bhargavg's suggestion first

Comment: Nope, was editing my answer before I saw your comment

Comment: ok, ok anyway `if(testCur.moveToFirst()){}` is way better then `testCur.moveToFirst(); if (!testCur.isAfterLast()){}`